# Improved way to deal with callbacks inside promises

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, es6-promise, asynccallback

I have the following code that uses `callbacks` inside `promises`:

```
const clue = 'someValue';

const myFunction = (someParam, callback) => {
    someAsyncOperation(someParam) // this function returns an array
    .then((array) => {
        if (array.includes(clue)){
            callback(null, array); // Callback with 'Success'
        }
        else{
            callback(`The array does not includes: ${clue}`); // Callback with Error
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        callback(`Some error inside the promise chain: ${err}`) // Callback with Error
    })
}
```

and call it like this:

```
myFunction (someParam, (error, response) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        // do something with the 'response'
    }    
})
```

Reading some documentation, I found that there is some improved way to do this:

```
const myFunction = (someParam, callback) => {
    someAsyncOperation(someParam) // this function returns an array
    .then((array) => {
        if (array.includes(clue)){
            callback(array);
        }
        else{
            callback(`The array does not includes: ${clue}`);
        }
    }, (e) => {
        callback(`Some error happened inside the promise chain: ${e}`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        callback(`Some error happened with callbacks: ${err}`)
    })
}
```

**My question:**

In the sense of performance or best practices, it's okay to call the `'callback' function` inside the promise as the two ways show or I'm doing something wrong, I mean some promise anti-pattern way ?

Comment: Pretty sure you should not have *both* an error handler (as the second argument to `.then`) *and* a `catch`. It's probably better to have only a single `catch`.

Comment: Also note that your second code, during success, is calling `callback` with `array` as the *first* argument (the `error`) rather than the second argument (the `response`).

Comment: So, based on what you say, it could be better the first one than the second one?

Comment: Don't use callbacks inside of promises - that is an anti-pattern.  Just return a promise and let the promise handle the notificaiton of completion or error.  That's what they are designed for.  The caller will then use `.then()` and `.catch()` on the returned promise instead of a callback.  This is the current state and future of Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you please, write an answer with an example of what you mean?

Comment: Don't *unpromisify*!

Comment: @robe007 - Per your request, I added an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems really backwards and takes away from the benefits of promises managing errors and passing them down the chain

Return the asynchronous promise from the function and don't interrupt it with callbacks. Then add a catch at the end of the chain

```
const myFunction = (someParam) => {
  // return the promise
  return someAsyncOperation(someParam) // this function returns an array
    .then((array) => {
      return array.includes(clue) ? array : [];
    });
}

myFunction(someParam).then(res=>{
  if(res.length){
     // do something with array
  }else{
     // no results
  }
}).catch(err=>console.log('Something went wrong in chain above this'))
```

Comment: This answer and `jfriend00's` answer are very good explained, but I select this becasue was the first. I can say that today I have learned again !

Answer (score 1):

Do not use callbacks from inside of promises, that is an anti-pattern.  Once you already have promises, just use them.  Don't "unpromisify" to turn them into callbacks - that's moving backwards in code structure.  Instead, just return the promise and you can then use `.then()` handlers to set what you want the resolved value to be or throw an error to set what you want the rejected reason to be:

```
const clue = 'someValue';

const myFunction = (someParam) => {
    return someAsyncOperation(someParam).then(array => {
        if (!array.includes(clue)){
            // reject promise
            throw new Error(`The array does not include: ${clue}`);
        }
        return array;
    });
}
```

Then, the caller would just do this:

```
myFunction(someData).then(array => {
    // success
    console.log(array);
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here which could be either your custom error
    // or an error from someAsyncOperation()
    console.log(err);
});
```

This gives you the advantage that the caller can use all the power of promises to synchronize this async operation with any others, to easily propagate errors all to one error handler, to use `await` with it, etc...

Comment: It is possible also to add a `catch` statement to `someAsyncOperation` right?

Comment: @robe007 - Yes, but there is no need unless you want to "handle" that error locally and not let the caller see that error directly.  If the `someAsyncOperation()` promise rejects, then your `.then()` will not be called and the caller will directly see the rejected promise and their own `.catch()` which they already need to have will see the error.